# GCP/GKE Add Network Tags

Tags: yaml, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to find a way to improve our infrastructure as code situation in GCP. My hope was that I could

1. Create a firewall rule whitelist based on target tags that are added by
2. Making target tags part of the deployment yaml config.

My hope was that by adding tags in a deployment I could have it auto apply those tags to any compute resource or load balancer that it creates. That way a firewall rule could be created, by terraform, that applies to those tags.

Am I going about this the wrong way or is there a way to do this? This is as much about automating firewall rule management as it is about cleaning up unnecessary rules that may interfere with operations.

Comment: Could you give an example of such rule? Are we talking only about `GKE` in that case? `GKE` cluster is a managed solution and it automatically does many things for you like firewall rules and Load Balancer configuration.

Comment: It does automatically do firewall rules but it doesn't let you customize them that I can tell. If I want to make it a whitelist rule that only allows a specific CIDR range I'm not aware of any means of doing that. I want to block traffic at layer 3 to the ingress or load balancer, only allowing our office or VPN ranges to access.

Answer (score 6):

GCP is actively using `network tags` to tag resources affected by firewall rules (allow,block). Those tags are connected with Compute Engine instances, Managed Groups and others.

Kubernetes is using `labels` to tag resources used with the service (exposing your app).

**Above `network tags` and `labels` are separate resources and they cannot be used together within `GCP/GKE` environment.**

Please take a look on official documentation regarding those resources:

- [Cloud.google.com: VPC: Network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags)
- [Kubernetes.io: Concepts: Labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/)

---

When you create a service of type `LoadBalancer` in `GKE`, you automatically create a forwarding rule for it. This rule can be later modified/edited. It can be edited to a state that it only allows requests from certain IP addresses like home/office etc.

It can be modified manually with `GCP Dashboard -> VPC Network -> Firewall`.

I found a **workaround** with Terraform that allows to modify existing forwarding rule created by a `GKE`.

---

Having above in mind I created an **example** for a `LoadBalancer` with Terraform and `GKE`. Steps:

- Spawning a workload.
- Exposing workload to external usage.
- Editing existing forwarding rule to block traffic from certain CIDR/s.

Assuming that:

- `Terraform` is installed and has access to `GCP`
- `GKE` cluster is already provisioned
- `kubectl` is set to connect to above cluster

For reference to above steps: [Learn.hashicorp.com: Terraform: Provision GKE cluster](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/kubernetes/provision-gke-cluster)

As for `Ingress`. Managing it will heavily depend on the solution used like:

- `ingress-nginx`
- `ingress-gce`

### Spawning a workload

Below example nginx `deployment` will be used to respond to request:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "nginx" {
  metadata {
    name = "scalable-nginx-example"
    labels = {
      App = "ScalableNginxExample"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 2
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        App = "ScalableNginxExample"
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          App = "ScalableNginxExample"
        }
      }
      spec {
        container {
          image = "nginx:1.7.8"
          name  = "example"

          port {
            container_port = 80
          }

          resources {
            limits {
              cpu    = "0.5"
              memory = "512Mi"
            }
            requests {
              cpu    = "50m"
              memory = "50Mi"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Exposing workload to external usage

Below definition will create service of type `LoadBalancer` for the nginx deployment:

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "nginx" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx-example"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      App = kubernetes_deployment.nginx.spec.0.template.0.metadata[0].labels.App
    }
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }

    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}

output "lb_ip" {

value = kubernetes_service.nginx.load_balancer_ingress[0].ip

}
```

`GKE` will automatically create a forwarding rule and assign IP address for a Load Balancer. **Terraform will not be aware of this forwarding rule and this forwarding rule will need to be imported to be able to modify it.**

Please take a specific look on part `lb_ip`. After successful run of `Terraform` this part will output an IP of a LoadBalancer. This value could be used to identify the forwarding rule associated with the service.

### Editing existing forwarding rule to block traffic from certain CIDR/s

As said above:

> **Terraform will not be aware of this forwarding rule and this forwarding rule will need to be imported to be able to modify it.**

**The issue here is that some self scripting is necessary to fully automate this workaround.**

Forwarding rule name is necessary to have an ability to modify it.

One of the ways to extract the forwarding rule name from `GCP` infrastructure is:

- Get the `LoadBalancer IP` from:

  - `$ kubectl get svc nginx-example`
- Get the `forwarding rule` name from:

  - `$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list --format=json`

> Disclaimer: 
>    Above command will output all firewall rules with details like target tags, priority and description in json format. `LoadBalancer IP` will be in the **description** section of a firewall rule.

- Extracted forwarding rule name should look similar to:

  - `k8s-fw-aefb2110aad9e11ea971d42010a9c00a`
- Use above name to create a resource in `Terraform`:

  - Create a desired definition of `forwarding rule` in file. Please take a look on below **example rule** and change according to your use case. This resource can be used as a template for another new resources. Please make sure that `target_tags` are the same as not modified version.

    Example definition of a forwarding rule:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "YOUR-NAME-OF-FORWARDING" {
  project = "PROJECT-NAME"
  provider = google-beta
  name = "k8s-fw-aefb2110aad9e11ea971d42010a9c00a"
  network = "PROJECT-NETWORK"
  source_ranges = ["1.2.3.4/32"]
  priority = "1000"
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports = ["80"]
    }
  target_tags = ["gke-PROJECT-NAME-gke-c6d3956c-node"] # 
  direction = "INGRESS"
  }
```

- Import resource with:

```
$ terraform import google_compute_firewall.YOUR-NAME-OF-FORWARDING projects/PROJECT-NAME/global/firewalls/k8s-fw-aefb2110aad9e11ea971d42010a9c00a`
```

When issuing `$ terraform apply` you should be able to see desired changes in your `forwarding rule` like below (part):

```
 ~ source_ranges           = [
     - "0.0.0.0/0",
     + "1.2.3.4/32",
   ]
```

**After applying your firewall rule to forward traffic should be modified!**